# T SQL - CASE or IF

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure in which I need to check to see:

```
 if @variable is null
 Then this
 Else that
```

In this case would it be better to use IF/ELSE or CASE or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `CASE` inside a `SELECT`, use `IF` outside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @variable IS NULL THEN 'IT IS NULL' ELSE 'NOT NULL' END
```

**Option 2:**

```
 SELECT COALESCE(@variable,'IT IS NULL')
```

**Option 3:**

```
SELECT ISNULL(@variable,'IT IS NULL')
```

All will come with Select Statement

**Option 4:**

```
IF @variable IS NULL

BEGIN 
   PRINT 'IT IS NULL'
END

ELSE
  PRINT 'IT IS NOT NULL'
```

Hope the picture is clear

Comment: You answered first and this worked for me (so far lol), thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

If *this* and *that* are SQL queries, I'd rather use `IF` statements.

Example:

```
if @status=0
    select * from #t where id=2
else
    select * from #t where names='nameHere'
```

But if they are values, use `CASE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @variable is null 
             THEN 'Nothing'
             ELSE 'Hello!'
        END) Status
FROM tableName
```